# How do I use c# List<string> to store multiple file paths in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-4, filepath

I am working on a small project with ASP.NET MVC 4 and .net framework 4.5. I have a class `RecReservation` to deal with user reservations. A user may make a reservation at first and upload 2-3 files later, the files have to be related to a certain reservation. At first I defined a string type in `RecReservation` to store file path, it worked, but only one file can be related to a reservation in this way, I need a solution to handle multiple file paths.

So I defined a `List<string> _recFilePath` in my `RecReservation` class to store the file paths. Each time a file is uploaded, the path of which should be appended to `_recFilePath`. The class looks like this:

```
public class RecReservation
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]      
    public int RecReservationID { get; set; }


    public String ProjectName { get; set; }

    [Required]            
    public string ProjectManager { get; set; }


    public String Department { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]   
    public DateTime ReservationDate { get; set; }


    public String ReservationTime { get; set; }

    [Required]                
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    [Required]      
    public string InstructorName { get; set; }

    [Required]     
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]    
    public string Description { get; set; }

    private List<string> _recFilePath = new List<string>();

    public List<string> RecFilePath
    {
        get
        { return _recFilePath; }
    }

    public void AddRecFilePath(string newpath)
    {
        _recFilePath.Add(newpath);
    }


}
```

In the database, I defined a `nvarchar(500)` data type for `_recFilePath`.

In the controller, I defined a pair of `RecUpload` overloads to deal with file uploads:

```
    public ViewResult RecUpload(int recReservationID)
    {
        RecReservation recReservation = repository.RecReservations.FirstOrDefault(p => p.RecReservationID == recReservationID);
        return View(recReservation);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RecUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, RecReservation recReservation)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/RecUploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        repository.AddFilePathToRec(recReservation, path);
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been uploaded", fileName);
        return RedirectToAction("AdminRecList");
    }
```

This is the implementation of  `AddFilePathToRec`

```
    public void AddFilePathToRec(RecReservation recReservation, string newFilePath)
    {
        RecReservation dbEntry = context.RecReservations.Find(recReservation.RecReservationID);
        if (dbEntry != null)
        {
            dbEntry.AddRecFilePath(newFilePath);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Now that I have tested the implementation, files upload works fine, but no path is added to `_recFilePath` field in my database. So what is the reason for this? Help is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: whats your db design? do you have separate table to store RecFilePath?
If not then you need to add separate table RecFilePath and have RecReservationID as Foreign Key in RecFilePath table.
Then you may just need to add new row in RecFilePath whenever user uploads new file in it.

Comment: @Murtaza Tahir Ali Thank you for reply! At this moment I am storing everything in one table, but yes, using a separate table and Foreign Key is a better solution, I'll try that.

Comment: A few days too late here but did you put a try-catch block around the code in the  `AddFilePathToRec` method? What if `dbEntry` is null? You still call `SaveChanges` regardless. Also change that line to `int rowsAffected = context.SaveChanges();` and see if you get back a value > 0. In short, you've got to do some basic debugging 101 or else you'll never know what went wrong.